# Windows Forms App Basics: Word document as a part of the Project (and how to edit it)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I need some help using the Word.Interop namespace in Visual Studio.  I am using VB.net, but C# answers are welcome as well.  I have a few different basic questions bolded below.

**I have a document (.docx) created and added to my project which is basically just a template**.  It contains all the proper formatting, but has string variables in the text which need to be replaced in a loop.  For example, if the string "COMPANYNAME" appears in the word document, I simply do a programmatic Find/Replace on that with the correct company name.  I continue in this fashion throughout the rest of the document, replacing all variables with their proper replacement:

```
Private Sub CompileInvoicesButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CompileInvoicesButton.Click
    For Each CompanyInfo In CompanyInfoList
        Dim wordApp As Word.Application
        wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Dim wordDoc As Word.Document = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Code\...\INVOICE.docx") '<-- Open template.  (how can I get the path of this document no matter where the application is being run from?)
        ' Replace the template text with real data:
        wordDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="<COMPANY NAME>", ReplaceWith:=CompanyInfo.CompanyName, Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
        wordDoc.SaveAs(folderpath + "\invoice1.docx")
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm running in to a few issues here, in this simple block of code.

**First**, upon trying to open up the file (ie. when I click the CompileInvoices button), I get a ReadOnly notification message which asks me if I want to open a copy of the file, or not.  I believe this is because the directory in which my project is located is marked ReadOnly, and the template document is, of course, located in my project directory.  My thought was that since the file is not large (a 1 page .docx), I would include it in my project and it would work fine this way as far as efficiency, but I did not forsee that ReadOnly issue.  How can I resolve this problem?  Apologies if this is a super basic question.  I did try to change some project settings around, but don't really know what I'm doing so I would appreciate some guidance before going ham.

**Second**, and perhaps this is related to the above, but how can I get the dynamic file path of the word document that I included?  Simply referring to the full path will not work on anyone's machine except for mine.

I think both of these problems may have to do with how/where I am including that INVOICE.docx file
in my project.  All I did was do a Right Click on my Project and go to Add Existing Item, and add it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `.Open`, which opens the template for editing, use the `.Add` method to create a new document from the template.

To get the current directory, you can use the `Application.StartupPath` property.

Comment: Do you have any example code of how I might use Application.StartuPath?  When I run my project this is set as the Debug folder, which doesn't have the file I want in it.

Comment: If it is included in your project then simply copy it to the output directory by setting the `Copy to Output Folder` property to true in the file properties.

Comment: Yes, that's the stuff I was messing around with.  I happened to have it changed to something else when I added in your example code.  Let's try it now...

Comment: I got it to accept that document path (it works) by fiddling around with those options and trying a lot of different combinations, as well as your example code.